# Why does ICEfaces send dispose-window request on page unload when using view-scoped bean?

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces

in our application ICEfaces always sends a dispose-window request just before navigating to another JSF Page. as much as i understand this should not happen when having org.icefaces.lazyWindowScope set to true and there is no window-scoped bean involved in current request. but it happens on each link and makes our UI less responsive. but we don't have any window-scoped bean in our application.

is that a bug in icefaces that the dispose request is sent when using view-scoped beans? Is it possible to disable? ViewScope is defined in JSF not in ICEfaces, it should work without this dispose request i guess...

```
@ManagedBean(name="viewScopeBean")
@ViewScoped
public class ViewScopeBean {
    public void doSomething(){
        //
    }
}
```

And here the example jsf:

```
<ice:form>
     <ice:commandButton value="doSomething" action="#{viewScopeBean.doSomething}"/>
     <h:link outcome="index" value="Link to same page"/>
</ice:form>
```

To reproduce do the following using the code above:

1. open firebug's net tab and activate persist option
2. click doSomething-Button
3. click "link to same page"
4. => dispose-window will be send before navigation

Dispose Request Parameters:

- ice.submit.type=ice.dispose.window
- ice.window=4guthcbue
- javax.faces.ViewState=-8138151632882151449%3A-6709064564386098402

Environment:

- ICEfaces-EE 2.0.0.GA
- ICEpush-EE 2.0.0.GA
- Mojarra 2.1.1
- JRockit 1.6.0_22
- WebLogic Server 10.3.4.0

ICEfaces Configuration:

- org.icefaces.render.auto: true [default]
- org.icefaces.autoid: true [default]
- org.icefaces.aria.enabled: true [default]
- org.icefaces.blockUIOnSubmit: false [default]
- org.icefaces.compressDOM: false [default]
- org.icefaces.compressResources: true [default]
- org.icefaces.connectionLostRedirectURI: /pages/main.jsf
- org.icefaces.deltaSubmit: false [default]
- org.icefaces.lazyPush: true [default]
- org.icefaces.sessionExpiredRedirectURI: /pages/main.jsf
- org.icefaces.standardFormSerialization: false [default]
- org.icefaces.strictSessionTimeout: false [default]
- org.icefaces.windowScopeExpiration = 1000 [default]
- org.icefaces.mandatoryResourceConfiguration: null [default]
- org.icefaces.uniqueResourceURLs: true [default]
- org.icefaces.lazyWindowScope: true [default]
- org.icefaces.disableDefaultErrorPopups: false [default]

Comment: In the [docs of icefaces](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/Configuration) i found the following: "Please note that if the view scope map contains any view scoped beans, lazyWindowScope is not enabled by default." But why? This means whenever a viewscoped bean is involved this request is send on page unload...

Comment: so it seems it was a bug in ICEfaces [http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE-7513](http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE-7513)

Comment: if you are sure not having any windowscoped bean, you can remove the page unload callback once the page is loaded: `window.onUnload = null;`. This works in our application.

Comment: i ment `window.onbeforeunload`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See comments and workaround above. It's a bug in icefaces.